# Are career development discussions allowed in Stack Overflow's chat rooms or not?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, chat

Are career development discussions allowed in chat rooms on Stack Overflow or not?

If not, is there any other site (or chat rooms of a site) where we can discuss career development issues in various technologies related to the programming field?

Comment: You can talk about anything in the chat room, from animals to quantum physics, as long as you find someone that wants to talk to you about it, and it is not offensive/universally illegal material. The problem is finding someone that is willing to listen and talk to you, and you'd find better chance in the chat room of the site that has anything to do with what you want to discuss.

Comment: Why downvotes? Please explain...It's general question...People sometimes discuss in chat room about career development that I've created...Sometimes other people asking me is it allowed or not? I have searched on MSO but didn't got any information..That's  I wanted to know is it allowed or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really no set answer to that. According to the [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq) this is what you can talk about:

> This site is an extension of Stack Overflow, so discussion should more
> or less revolve around the same topics you'd find at Stack Overflow —
> but in an interactive, less strictly Q&A focused way. Do have fun, but
> please keep it professional and always be respectful of your fellow
> community members.

That does not seem to explicitly render career development discussions off-topic. Do keep in mind though that the various chat rooms might have their own distinct culture and ideas of what is on-topic or not.

Just as you wouldn't stumble into a bar to start rambling about career development issues with the people there (or at least I hope you wouldn't), perhaps ask first whether or not the topic is something they are interested in discussing. If they are not, then move on. In the "worst" case you could even start your own chat-room. But then you'd have to wait for interested parties to come talk to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a site-proposal for career development questions, specifically:   http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49221/career-development?referrer=vM2JF8RshPsqFxFwY0KYOQ2